# How to get an initial selected value in a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Model

```
        public class SModel
        {
            public string ddlLocation { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> locationItems { get; set; }
        }
```

Controller

```
     [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult StudyScheduler(SModel model)
     {
        model.spLocationItems = FillLocation();
        //Here i have to fill other dropdownlist on selected value of location.
        return View();
     }

    private List<SelectListItem> FillLocation()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        //Fill items from DB
          return items;
    }
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ddlLocation, new SelectList(Model.locationItems, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "cssTextbox", style = "width:90%" })
```

How to get an initial selected value in a dropdownlist and pass to some function to fill other dropdownlist.

Comment: Where do you want to get the initial selected value, in the controller, in client side script or...?

Comment: immediately after first ddl fill

Comment: @NikhilD You are trying to create `cascading drop downs`. 

There are plenty of examples on the internet and some similar questions are answered in SO like this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195224/making-cascading-dropdownlist

Try this http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/b58fde6b-415e-454d-985b-d5dc4ad2fca8.aspx or even this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJ_VjyxAMT4 or just google for `asp.net mvc cascading dropdown`

Answer (score 0):

You can use 4th parameter of `SelectList()`.

```
new SelectList(items, "value", "text", "please select");
```

**So, your code will be**

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ddlLocation, 
    new SelectList(Model.locationItems, "Value", "Text","please select"), 
new { @class = "cssTextbox", style = "width:90%" })
```

Comment: Ashwini want to get the initial selected value, in the controller, immediately after first ddl fill.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the initial value you want to be selected in the dropdown from controller.

Like ddlLocation={selected value to be selected on load}- then the value will be selected in the first dropdown. you can use the same value to send it to other function.

I hope this is what you are looking for. Please ignore if not.

Thank you

Comment: How i get selected value